# Cases with brackets instead of curly brackets

Tags: cases

How could I use cases with [] (both sides) instead of curly bracket as the attached picture shows?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a bit more context, e.g. a minimal working example. Without anything, I can only guess that `Bmatrix` could help. `cases` is intentionally one-sided.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the lack of context. I wrote "cases" because I know it's one-sided. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
  a=
  \left[\begin{aligned}
    &2 \rightarrow \text{John}\\
    &5 \rightarrow \text{Mary}\\
    &7 \rightarrow \text{Ann}
  \end{aligned}\right]\]
  \[
  a=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 &\rightarrow &\text{John}\\
    5 &\rightarrow &\text{Mary}\\
    7 &\rightarrow &\text{Ann}
  \end{bmatrix}\]
  \[
  a=
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}l@{\,}l@{\,}c@{}}
    2 &\rightarrow &\text{John}\\
    5 &\rightarrow &\text{Mary}\\
    7 &\rightarrow &\text{Ann}
  \end{array}\right]
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]